# Populate select menu onChange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap select menu which I want to populate onChange from another select menu. I think I have some problems with returning the data from PHP.

Select menu:

```
            <div class="col-md-6" style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
                    <span style="width:50%;" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Municipality *</span>
                    <select class="selectpicker" name="object_Municipality" id="object_Municipality">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected" >Municipality *</option>                          
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript function (called onChange from another select menu) to populate the select menu:

```
function populate_obcina(value) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("object_Municipality").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","get_Municipality.php?q="+value,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

My get_Municipality.php file:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'functions.php';
    $conn = dbConnect();

    $q =($_GET['q']);

        $municipality = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id,municipality FROM municipalities  WHERE `region`='".$q."'") or die(file_put_contents('error_querry.txt', print_r("Error: " . mysqli_error($conn), true)));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($municipality, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

      $fp = fopen("while_loop.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open log file for writing.");
      fwrite($fp, PHP_EOL .'<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['municipality'].'</option>');
      fflush($fp);
      fclose($fp);      

      //In the while_loop.txt I get lines like this:
      //<option value="1">Chicago</option>
      //so I guess the problem is the way I am returning the results    

  echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['municipality'].'</option>';
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

This is the return I get:

```
<option value="1">Chicago</option><option value="2">LA</option><option value="3">California</option>
```

Comment: First, why don't you use jquery $.ajax for your queries if you're using jquery? Then, What does your xmlhttprequest return? Do you see something? Use console and check this... and where is your event handler calling the populate function?

Comment: Can you implement your code sample in a JavaScript snippet or on a JSFiddle?

Comment: I have edited the question: the return I get looks ok..it's like it is not refreshing my select menu. I don't know how to implement this in jsfiddle or snippet because I use database data here..

Comment: Yes I see, how many rows are you supposed to retrieve? The 3 you're showing or more? Are you using jquery?

Comment: Is this the only list you will have to populate like this? or you will have to populate some other lists with other data somewhere else?

Comment: I am supposed to retrieve between 3-25 rows, depends.. i am using query 1.8.3.min. I already used the same code and it worked..the only thing that change is that now I have a bootstrap select picker..

Comment: ... Are you using jquery? Is this the only list you will have to fill like this?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.3.min, is that what you mean? Yes I will have more list to populate..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83173/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-zetaal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already did that kind of job, but I did it differently since I had to be able to populate many kinds of selects, on events, with pre-chosen data or not, ... with Jquery, bootstrap, & so on...

SELECT HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
        <span style="width:50%;" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Municipality *</span>
        <select class="selectpicker" name="object_Municipality" id="object_Municipality">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" >Municipality *</option>                          
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery populate "class", just make a file called PopulateList.js like this :

```
function PopulateList(){ }

PopulateList.municipality = function(element,choice){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : './getMunicipalitiesChoice.php',
            data  : {'choice':choice},
            dataType : 'json',
            error : function(response){
                alert('SOMETHING WENT WRONG');
            },
            success : function(response){
                element.html(response);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

JQuery On change event :

```
$(document).on('change','#listFiringTheEvent',function(){
    //Call the populate function here
    populateList.municipality('#object_Municipality',$(this).val());
});
```

PHP getMunicipalitiesChoice.php :

```
<?php
    require_once 'functions.php';
    if(isset($_POST['choice'])){
        $conn = dbConnect();
        $q = $_POST['choice'];
        $result = '';
        $municipality = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id,municipality FROM municipalities  WHERE `region`='".$q."'") or die(file_put_contents('error_querry.txt', print_r("Error: " . mysqli_error($conn), true)));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($municipality, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $fp = fopen("while_loop.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open log file for writing.");
            fwrite($fp, PHP_EOL .'<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['municipality'].'</option>');
            fflush($fp);
            fclose($fp);
            $result.='<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['municipality'].'</option>';
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }else{
        //If you're here, that's because the file has been called with a "invalid" choice (not set)
    }
?>
```

Now, as you said, if you have some other lists to fill, just add functions in your PopulateList.js file like this, for example, a function that fills a list with ALL municipalities, not depending on any choice :

```
PopulateList.municipalities = function(element){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : './getMunicipalities.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            error : function(response){},
            success : function(response){
                element.html(response);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

OR for example you fill a "cities" list when you chose a "municipality" :

```
PopulateList.citiesOnMunicipality= function(element,municipality){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : './getCitiesOnMunicipality.php',
            data : {'municipality':municipality},
            dataType : 'json',
            error : function(response){},
            success : function(response){
                element.html(response);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

In my example here, I assume that your html and php code are "good".

But (for PHP) you have to use prepared statements...

Hope this helps!